# Multiple foreign keys referencing same table column in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a rating system. Rating is a table which contains individual ratings as rows. Each rating has a "rater" and a "ratee". These two columns reference a different table, "User", by means of a foreign key. However, they both reference the same user.id column. Code:

```
class Rating(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  rater_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
  ratee_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
```

And here is how they are represented from within the User class (table):

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  username = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True, nullable=False)
  ratesOfOthers = db.relationship('Rating', backref='rater', lazy=True)
  ratingsByOthers = db.relationship('Rating', backref='ratee', lazy=True)
```

Now, when I try to use this relationship, I am presented with the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.ratesOfOthers - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables. Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

I have tried using the foreign_keys argument from inside the User class, but that did nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption is that in your scenario a user can rate other users, and they (themselves) can be rated. Basically, there is one table called `User` referencing other users within an application.

A relationship in which instances of a class are linked to other instances of the same class is called *self-referential relationship*, and that is exactly what you have here.

Here is a diagram that represents this self-referential many-to-many relationship that keeps track of ratings:

[image]

The `Ratings` table is the association table of the relationship. The foreign keys in this table are pointing at entries in the `User` table since it is linking users to users.

To add this table to your database, this is how you can go about it:

```py
ratings = db.Table('ratings'
                   db.Column('my_ratings_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
                   db.Column('other_people_rating_id', db.Integet, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
                   )
```

This is an auxiliary table (directly-translated as seen above) that has no data other than foreign keys. It is, therefore, created without an associated model class.

To declare the many-to-many relationship in the `User` table, add this:

```py
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True, nullable=False)
    
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.username}'
        
    my_ratings = db.relationship(
                                 'User',
                                 secondary=ratings,
                                 primaryjoin=(ratings.c.my_ratings_id == id),
                                 secondaryjoin=(ratings.c.other_people_rating_id == id),
                                 backref = db.backref('other_people_rating', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic'
                                 )
```

I am defining the relationship as seen from the left side user with the name `my_ratings` because when you query this relationship from the left side, you will get a list of all those on the right side. Visually, this is what I mean:

[image]

Examining all the arguments of the `db.relationship()` call, you will see that:

- `User` is the right side entity of the relationship.
- `secondary` configures the `ratings` association table
- `primaryjoin` indicates the condition that links the left side entity with the association table. The `user id` should match `my_ratings_id`
- `secondaryjoin` indicates the condition that links the right side entity with the association table. Again, `other_people_rating_id` should match the `user` id
- `backref` defines how this relationship will be accessed from the right side entity. From the left side, the relationship is named `my_ratings`, so from the right side, I decided to name it `other_people_rating` to represent all the left side users that are linked to the target user in the right side.
- The `dynamic` mode is used to set up the query to not run until specifically requested.
- The second `lazy` parameter applies to the left side query instead of the right side.

Comment: This was a great answer. Thank you for the thorough explanation, I learned a lot.